# Why doesn't the wp_add_inline_script function add js code?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to use wp_add_inline_script function in wordpress in my custom block.

```
function bd_dodaj_skrypty() {
  $result = wp_add_inline_script(
    'wp-block-navigation-view-js',
    'console.log("inline działa")',
    'before' // 'after'
  );

  if ($result) {
  echo "true";
  }
  else {
  echo "false";
  }
}
```

I of course added the function to a hook:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bd_dodaj_skrypty');
```

Why wp_add_inline_script() returns false?

Script with id:"wp-block-navigation-view-js" exists after page refresh. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to register handle:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bd_dodaj_skrypty'); 
function bd_dodaj_skrypty() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-block-navigation-view-js', 'https://url-to/my- 
                   script.js' );
    $result = wp_add_inline_script(
    'wp-block-navigation-view-js',
    'console.log("inline działa")',
    'before' // 'after'
    );

   if ($result) {
     echo "true";
    }else {
        echo "false";
    }
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Using wp_enqueue_script in my opinion is not necessary. File frontend.js to which I want to add another js code was registered in block.json file: "viewScript": "file:./frontend.js".